# Replace NaN with Value but result not being retained

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Does anyone see why the 834 is not being retained?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace is not in-place operation, it returns a modified copy, you need to reassign it to your data frame.

Comment: This still doesn't work but I am sure your answer is correct.  What is wrong with the below?
Purchase[Purchase["Loan_Key"] == 21607540]["Co_Applicant_Fico_Auto_Industry_Adjusted_Score_Nbr"].fillna(834, inplace=True)
Purchase[Purchase["Loan_Key"] == 21607540]["Co_Applicant_Fico_Auto_Industry_Adjusted_Score_Nbr"]

Comment: This seems to have worked:
Purchase.loc[8188, 'Co_Applicant_Fico_Auto_Industry_Adjusted_Score_Nbr'] = 834
Purchase.loc[8188, 'Co_Applicant_Fico_Auto_Industry_Adjusted_Score_Nbr']